# Как парсить html страничку с JavaScript в python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Хочу парсить страничку с javascript. Пробовал с requests, BeautifulSoup, но пишет, что надо включить javascript

```
Please turn JavaScript on and reload the page.
```

Comment: Например selenium

Comment: Ну или requests-html

Comment: Через  requests-html не дает. Тоже надо включить javascript

Comment: Ну Вы хоть ссылку на страницу которую парсить пытаетесь дайте. Просто у меня есть впечатление, что Вы requests-html неправильно юзаете

Comment: https://arizona-rp.com/fractions/phoenix/1/ пытаюсь получить список ников

Comment: А закосить под браузер не пробывали?

Answer (score 0):

Заходим на страницу в браузере заходим в интрументы веб-разработчика в вкладку сеть копируем куки и заголовки запроса(хендлеры). В коде отпраляем GET запрос на страницу с прописанными куки и хендлеры, которые мы сопировали из браузера. Получаем нужный нам HTML